# What is the optimal scene size?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, levels, scene

I'm coding a small *"Binding of Isaac"*-like game, with a little help from [the official "Scavengers" Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/s/2d-roguelike-tutorial), since it's my first game.

In the tutorial every level is comprised of only one room. The player moves around and, when it reaches the ending, the whole scene is reloaded, creating a new procedurally generated map, but I wanted to do something different on my game.

My idea is to have levels comprised of a procedurally generated maze of many many rooms and the player should be able to navigate across them back and forth at will, but I'm unsure about using a scene per room or per level.

> **Q:** What is the ideal size (in terms of gameplay content) for a scene?
>
> Is the act of loading scenes resource-expensive (therefore prohibiting it's frequent use)?
>
> Are there relevant performance differences between using many small scenes versus using one big scene?
>
> Should I make every room a scene just like the tutorial, or should I make a bigger scene for the whole level?

Comment: Welcome to GameDev.SE. In my opinion, the question you should be asking is whether it would be _easier for you to develop_ one scene per level or one scene per room. The optimization part is relatively simpler with the help of profiler.

Comment: You can make both work, and performance costs of loading resources are manageable by asynchronously pre-loading before you need them. So there's no one optimal size. Work the way that makes sense to you, and if you encounter a problem like load times, ask about how to solve that problem.